# VB.Net Stream Bitmap/Image TO FFMpeg is not working :(

Tags: vb.net, stream, ffmpeg

I m trying to port images to FFMpeg using StandardInput. It's not working somehow? :(

it's throwing me bellow error :(

[image]

Here is the code i tried:

```
    Dim objBitmap As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim objFProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim objStream As System.IO.BinaryWriter
    Dim strFiles() As String
    Dim strEachFile As String
    Dim intFile As Integer
    Dim intFrame As Integer
    Dim intFLoop As Integer
    objFProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process
    objFProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\ffmpeg.exe"
    objFProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-r 1 -f image2pipe -i pipe:.bmp -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 35.0 -vcodec libx264 -an -coder 1 -rc_lookahead 50 -threads 0 D:\test.mp4"
    objFProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    objFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    objFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    objFProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    rem objFProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    rem objFProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    objFProcess.Start()
    objStream = New System.IO.BinaryWriter(objFProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream)
    strFiles = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText().Split({System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    intFrame = 0
    intFile = 0
    For Each strEachFile In strFiles
        rem MessageBox.Show(strEachFile)
        intFile = intFile + 1
        objBitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(strEachFile)
        For intFLoop = 0 To 24
            intFrame = intFrame + 1
            cmd1.Text = intFile.ToString & "-" & intFrame.ToString
            My.Application.DoEvents()
            objBitmap.Save(objStream.BaseStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp) Rem this line give me above (attached) error :(
        Next
        objBitmap.Dispose()
    Next
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    objStream.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
    rem objFProcess.Kill()
```

any help would be highly appreciated

thanks in advance...

Edit-1:
As asked by some one :) here is:

View Detail Result: (Sorry, the image is very large in width/height)

[image]

And here is the Copy Details Result:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
ErrorCode=-2147467259
Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
Source=System.Drawing
StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
   at FFMpeg_Stream.Form1.cmd1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in g:\My Documents\FFMpeg Stream\FFMpeg Stream\Form1.vb:line 40
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at FFMpeg_Stream.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

that's all i can give as information :(

Comment: You should probably provide us the detailed exception and stacktrace, and the files or ressources which allows to reproduce it. Currently you don't give all required informations.

Comment: @AFract; sir, give full source code along with the error message/image. What else you need?

Comment: Does the running user have the proper rights to those folders?

Comment: what is on the clipboard and how did it get there?

Comment: @the_lotus, yes sir, running user is me and i am and admin for the system/computer and i have full access everywhere :)

Comment: @Plutonix, first i copy the image names (of course with full path) in clipboard, then run that code (by clicking on the button)

sir, if i just change the save parameter from "objStream.BaseStream" to local path like "D:\Save.bmp" it does work and no error.

so, i think it's something with that process/stream or something like that. I am not sure about :(

Comment: @Zakir_SZH : exactly what I said. An exception message is not a whole exception (click on "View details" for example). At the first glance your code also rely on ffmpeg (version ?) and the obscure content of your clipboard. Try to narrow your question and/or provide requested details.

Comment: @AFract with the Generic Error in GDI, that is all you get - there is no inner exception and the error covers many possible causes

Comment: I suggest you search for "Generic Error in GDI+" that error has so many different solution. You can't find a bunch of them here. I'm pretty sure your problem has nothing to do with ffmpeg but with System.Drawing.Bitmap

Comment: @the_lotus, sir i am sorry but if it has issue with System.Drawing.Bitmap then how it saved to local file fine? it's only making issue to write to that stream :(

Comment: @AFract, sir, please see the post again, i have added the information you have asked for. And also in reply to Plutonix, i told clipboard just hold the file names for the images.

Comment: So as I told previously : try to narrow down. We don't care about clipboard and so. Everything looks like to be related to Bitmap.Save, and to output of ffmpeg. Therefore my advice would be : try first to save the output stream in binary format, to get sure it is correct, then only try to feed Bitmap.Save with it. And all the rest of code is useless... GDI+ is really sensitive and fails easily, with very unclear errors. So you have to be sure of what you give to it as input and parameters...

Comment: seems silly to paste the names to the clipboard and then split them back out to use them.  Just use a List(Of String).  Then, check that the stream you are writing to can be written to (set a breakpoint and use the debugger).   Since you are writing a **bitmap** to a **stream** the underlying problem could be with those or badly parsed filenames

Comment: @Plutonix, sir, it nothing with file names. I use clipboard just to make the test faster/shorter. Because i can copy multiple file names to clipboard sing short cut key on a file manager. And also i don't think there is nothing with parsing files names because it's load the image to bitmap image successfully all is just failed to stream :(

and also a information, (that might help) if i change the image format from bmp to jpg then it shows no error. Though it just don't every create any output file or shows any message on FFMPEG output window.